# Convert string join utility function into LINQ equivalent

Tags: c#, string, linq

So I have a helper function that takes a particular list, performs a loop and returns a string joined with comma without duplication.

```
public static string GetJoinedEquipString(List<MeasuredData> dataList)
{
    HashSet<string> equipSet = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (MeasuredData data in dataList)
    {
        equipSet.Add(data.GetEquipNumString());
    }
    return String.Join(",", equipNumSet.ToArray());
}
```

Which works fine.. but is there a way to rewrite this hideous looking function using LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
string.Join(",", dataList.Select(d => d.GetEquipNumString()).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Instead of using a `HashSet` to make the list unique, look at `Distinct`, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).  This will use the default equality comparer for `string` (as does your implementation), but there is also an overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer` if you are ever using more complex objects.

If you're using .NET 4.0 or newer, you can leave off the call to `ToArray` since an overload of `Join` was added that has an `IEnumerable<string>` as a parameter (as opposed to just `string[]`).

Comment: Nice! But shouldn't I add .ToArray() as String.Join only takes in string[] as parameter?

Comment: Nope - there is also an overload that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx

Comment: Oh.. weird, I don't see the overload. Perhaps it's because I'm using .NET 3.5? Edit: Yup. The overloaded method was added in 4.0